# Как разделить число на "подчисла"?

Tags: python, числа

Всем доброго дня. Не могу никак разобраться как разделить число на "подчисла".

То есть чтобы 5348 стало:

```
5000
300
40
8
```

С учетом того, что число может быть больше миллиона, а может меньше 10. То есть условия на количество знаков после первого символа тут, вероятно, не подходят

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
num = "570820"

sub_numbers = [num[i] + '0' * (len(num) - i - 1)
               for i in range(len(num))
               if num[i] != '0']

print('\n'.join(sub_numbers))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 500000
> 70000
> 800
> 20
> ```

Comment: Да, то, что нужно. Спасибо! Как всегда кажется что всё просто, когда видишь решение)

Comment: @ProTask забыл учесть то, что нули не стоит выводить, исправил и сейчас все хорошо)